# How to install wine in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, wine

I'm unable to install wine in ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

is giving me this error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

Please help soon

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: If you have not tried to install wine before (or if you cleaned up the mess from failed attempts), then it's a simple `sudo apt install wine`. The *real* question is what prior attempts you made, and what PPAs and other non-Ubuntu sources you used, so we can advise you how to clean up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go one-by-one and install each of these dependencies to see what the problem is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Please post any errors, thanks.

Comment: @catch_me first, determine which version of wine you need to achieve your goals Second, if you need a specific wine version, I suggest looking at the Wine PPA channels

Comment: @user175999 This seems pretty irrelevant to the error. When you go to install the specific versions explicitly, there should be an additional error describing what is impossible about the situation. Most of the time there is no specific version needed and ppa is not recommended unless that is the case.

Comment: it is important because to determine the necessary steps to provide a solution, we need to know which packages to remove and un-break in some kind of package manager

Comment: @user175999 That's what I'm doing and I'm an expert at package management and haven't met a broken package management setup I couldn't fix in at least a couple of years now.

Comment: never said your answer was wrong...just saying that there are other ways to the same destination

Comment: This is why we should be able to downvote comments, so that we can all weigh in on the issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42688/discussion-between-user175999-and-mchid).

Comment: This is the error which i'm getting while installing wine1.6                                       
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: @catch_me Thanks, I have updated the answer. Please post any more errors.